# How do I query Firebase to do the following?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to take only the Email IDs out of my current database and create a new node called 'EmailList' which has the list of emails. How do I go about doing this?

This is a snapshot of my Database: [image]

Comment: you want the emails?

Comment: are the emails always at index 3?

Comment: Yes, the emails are always at index 3. And yes, I want just the emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("masterSheet");
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
String email=data.child("3").getValue().toString();
DatabaseReference refs=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("EmailList").push();
 refs.child("email").setValue(email);
      }
   }

@Override
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {


 }
 });
```

Here you have the snapshot which is `masterSheet` then you iterate inside the children of `masterSheet` and get the value of child("3") which is the email and then you create a new reference, inside `onDatachange` (since its asynchronous) with parent node `EmailList`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I have a small doubt. If I put a condition within the for loop to compare whether the email is NULL or not, the condition doesn't seem to get executed. Why is that?

for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
String email=data.child("3").getValue().toString();
if(email != ""){
DatabaseReference refs=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("EmailList").push();
 refs.child("email").setValue(email);
}
      }

Comment: write this `if (email != null)`

Comment: @ArjunRam maybe the email is sometimes null in the database if child(3) does not have an email then its not null, if you remove the condition it works right?

Comment: What I meant was that even if I add that condition, the code executes as though the condition never existed at all. Because if I have data.child("3").getValue().toString() to be null or "", I don't want that particular email to be added to the new EmailList node. However, that node is still added for some reason.

Comment: it executes since `child("3")` is not null, if it was null it wont be added to the `EmailList`. If it is null then there will be no email to be added anw..

Comment: But child("3") is null for the first node in my case. See this:
https://imgur.com/a/yVePF

Comment: try `if(email.isEmpty()){ //do nothing} else{ //add in the list} ` or try `if(email.equals(" ")){ //do nothing else{ //add in the list}` @ArjunRam

Comment: yes because the email is not null it is there but its just empty

Comment: Ah, okay got it!

Answer (score 0):

```
 final ArrayList<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();
        DatabaseReference masterSheetReferebce =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("masterSheet");
        masterSheetReferebce.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
                //Get All the emails 
                for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String email=data.child("3").getValue().toString();
                    emails.add(email);
                }
                //Instead of posting everytime just post it once
                //adding email list to child EmailList
                DatabaseReference emailListReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("EmailList");
                emailListReference.setValue(emails);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }

        });
```